# What is the proper transcription of these Einsteinian equations?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature, notation

I’m updating an ebook edition of a science fiction story by Fritz Leiber, *Nice Girl with 5 Husbands*. (Its copyright has expired.) The final paragraph of the story reads:

> In his casual reading he ran across popular science articles describing the binary system of numbers used in electronic calculating machines, where one and one make ten. He always skipped them. And more than once he saw the four equations expressing Einstein’s generalized theory of gravitation:
>
> [image: gik;l=0 ; Γi=0 ; Rik=0 ; ,is∨s=0]
>
> He never connected them with the little girl’s chant: “Gik-lo, I-o, Rik-o, Gis-so.”

I’m trying to transcribe the equation to MathML, but I’m not sure what equations are being referenced, what letters represent variables versus subscripts or superscripts, or even the meaning of a single operator besides $=$.

I gather that $g^{iK}$ is a “Hermitian tensor,” although I don’t know what $+$, $-$, $;$, or $l$ mean (are the $+$ and $-$ meant to align under $i$ and $K$ respectively?); the second and third equations seem straightforward although I don’t know if those are actually subscripts; and in the fourth equation the first variable appears to be fraktur $g$; I’m not sure if the letters above the $\vee$ are symbols $is$ or the (unitalicized) English word “is”. So my best guess is:

$$g^{iK}_{+-};l=0$$

$$\Gamma_i = 0$$

$$R_{ik} = 0$$

$$\mathfrak{g},\overset{is}{\underset{s}{\vee}} = 0$$

Is it correct?

---

**Edit**:

A comment questioned whether these are real equations at all. With a bit of searching I was able to find a 1945 paper by Einstein, “A Generalization of the Relativistic Theory of Gravitation,” which describes four equations:

$$0 = g_{\overset{ik}{+-};l} = g_{ik,l} = g_{ak}\Gamma^a_{il} - g_{ia}\Gamma^a_{lk}$$

$$0 = G_{ik} = \Gamma^a_{ik,a} - \Gamma^a_{ib}\Gamma^b_{ak} = (\log\sqrt{-g})_{,i,k} + (\log\sqrt{-g})_{,a}\Gamma^a_{ik} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{-g}}(\mathfrak{g}^{ab}\Gamma_b)_{,a}g_{ik}$$

I don’t understand the math or the physics well enough to understand if these are equivalent, but the first equation at least shows up verbatim (although I’m still not sure if I wrote the TeX correctly).

Comment: No, it’s mostly gobbledygook. Only $R_{ik}=0$ makes any sense. If you try to turn it into real equations you won’t be respecting the author’s intentions.

Comment: I just noticed it says Einstein’s *generalized* theory of gravitation. If this is a later theory he developed after General Relativity, I don’t know what the equations for it look like. (I only know GR; his later work was mostly unsuccessful.) But I’m still skeptical that this is real math.

Comment: This is history of science not mainstream physics.

Comment: The papers are *A Generalization of the Relativistic Theory of Gravitation, Annals of Mathematics , Oct., 1945, Second Series, Vol. 46, No. 4 (Oct., 1945), pp. 578-584* and *A Generalization of the Relativistic Theory of Gravitation, II, Annals of Mathematics, Oct., 1946, Second Series, Vol. 47, No. 4 (Oct., 1946), pp. 731-741*. However I doubt Leiber got the equations from these papers as they are impenetrable for the non-specialist. Apparently the equations were published in The New York Times, and my guess is that Leiber saw them there.

Comment: [This is the NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/1949/12/27/archives/new-einstein-theory-gives-a-master-key-to-universe-scientist-after.html). The preview is just big enough for you to see that the four equations are there, but not big enough to see clearly. If you can find a full size version I would guess these will be what Leiber reproduced.

Comment: This might be better moved to Science Fiction & Fantasy.

Comment: I don’t think moving to SFF makes sense as the question and answer have nothing to do with science fiction. But John’s suggestion of the History of Science and Mathematics SE might be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to helpful suggestions from John Rennie, I found the New York Times article whence Leiber most likely got the equations:

[image: Einstein’s published “equations for the non‐symmetrical field”]

Between this and comparing to typeset copies of Einstein’s two papers on the subject, I’m feeling fairly confident in marking up the equations as follows:

$$g_{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{ik}{+-};l} = 0$$

$$\Gamma_i = 0$$

$$R_{ik} = 0$$

$${\mathfrak{g}^{{is}}}_{,s} = 0$$

(In the MathML I included a ˇ below $is$, although I haven’t figured out how to include it in MathJAX for this answer.)